# execute lines of code Simultaneous in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have developed a website using asp.net in C#.

When a user click on a button I have to collect some data from servers and show results. My code is something like this:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string string1 = new MyServer1().SendRequest("Request1");

         string string2 = new MyServer2().SendRequest("Request2");

         string string3 = new MyServer3().SendRequest("Request3");

         string string4 = new MyServer4().SendRequest("Request4");

         Response.Write(string1 + string2 + string3 + string4);
      }
 }
```

Each `SendRequest` method takes a long time (between 20 to 40 seconds) to return result. Is it possible to run all `SendRequest` methods simultaneously and when all have executed show results?

Comment: Does your Server-Object contain a SendRequestAsync-Method?

Comment: Then y should look at the answer of @Micke - this is the way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TaskFactory.StartNew()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew%60%601%22);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to run multiple tasks asynchronously. Each call returns a `Task<string>`. Then use `WaitAll` to wait for all tasks to complete. The return value will be available in the `Result` property.

The following example will execute in 20 seconds, instead of 80:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = new Task<string>[4];

            tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyServer1().SendRequest("Request1"));
            tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyServer2().SendRequest("Request2"));
            tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyServer3().SendRequest("Request3"));
            tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyServer4().SendRequest("Request4"));

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            var string1 = tasks[0].Result;
            var string2 = tasks[1].Result;
            var string3 = tasks[2].Result;
            var string4 = tasks[3].Result;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", string1, string2, string3, string4);
        }
    }

    public abstract class MyServer
    {
        public string SendRequest(string request)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20000);

            return request.Replace("Request", "Response");
        }
    }

    public class MyServer1 : MyServer {}
    public class MyServer2 : MyServer {}
    public class MyServer3 : MyServer {}
    public class MyServer4 : MyServer {}
}
```

---

```
Response1 Response2 Response3 Response4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to run the above requests in asynchronous mode.  Basically, you need to wrap calls to `new MyServerX().SendRequest("RequestX");` to a process that  returns control immediately back to the caller without waiting for it to finish.

Please see [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) . This should help.